# Using commas when chaining verbs

Tags: punctuation

When chaining verbs, especially long sentences during writing, is it common (and grammatically correct) to use commas? For example:

> 食堂に行って、焼うどんを食べて、帰ってくる

Personally, I find it harder to read without the commas (especially when particles are ommited. Eg: 食堂行って焼うどん食べて帰ってくる). So a second question, if I do not attach the commas, will it be legible/readable and grammatically correct? (Imagine を particles getting omitted and the list of verbs goes on and on)

Comment: `食堂にいて` You meant to type 食堂にい**っ**て ([行]{い}って), no?

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks. Edited

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no hard rule, so you can use a lot of discretion. A lot of it is a matter of style. It's definitely common to use it in your situation, as it clearly makes it easier to read.

If you don't use commas in that sentence, it's still ok (at least for experienced readers). It should also be grammatically correct.

[Here](https://prowriters.jp/blog/20) is some guideline. However, don't take it as gospel. There are different styles and preferences.

Comment: thanks. I'll take that as it is optional to use punctuations in this particular case, ie: whether we use them or not, it is still grammatically correct